# Is it possible to use Struts 1.1 and Spring MVC simultaneously?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, web, frameworks, struts

As the title states I have in mind using Struts 1.1 and Spring MVC simultaneously.
There's a huge project using Struts 1.1 which is undoubtly outdated, but the effort to completely migrate to Spring MVC would be way too big.
So the plan is to use both of them, making some things easier.
Is this generally possible and how could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1.1 support has been removed in version 4.0 but it's supported on 3.2.x

see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts

Comment: Is this just about Spring or about Spring Web MVC?

Comment: @user3168471 It's allows you to manage structs actions with the spring IoC container. Struts request are still handled by the ActionServlet.